# How to unpickle from string?

Tags: python, pickle

I have a series of Pickle files that are compressed using gzip. Due to size issue, I read the file in the gzip compressed format and decompress them in the memory only when I need them. That is,

```
my_zip_content = open(file_name, 'rb').read()
my_pickle_content = zlib.decompress(my_zip_content, 15 + 32)
original_content = UNPICKLE(my_pickle_content) # How ?
```

The problem is, I cannot find an API (i.e., `UNPICKLE`) to unpickle string. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The [pickle.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads) is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `pickle.loads()` which means "load string," see https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads